# How to find he Kpn,Kpp parameters for the given 130nm CMOS models using LtSpice?

Tags: ltspice, cmos

The model file is present at http://ptm.asu.edu/modelcard/2006/130nm_bulk.pm
I tried finding the value of unCox by finding the value of drain current, gate-source voltage and the threshold voltage for the nmos, but I got varying results for different simulations, varying from 500uA/V^2 to 1500 uA/V^2. Same variation was there in the pmos simulations too. is there a way to find the value of unCox and upCox from the model files?

Comment: How did you try? If the method doesn't change, the numbers shouldn't change.

Comment: Honestly for the type of work you're doing that's probably not a huge error. When I took semiconductor physics back in college, as long as we're with an order of magnitude was usually considered decent. At least for a first-level approach

Comment: For the nmos, i first fixed the Vds at 0.8V and Vgs at 0.6V for that the unCox i calculated using the Id was near 600uA/V^2. Then for 1V vds and 0.8V Vgs, i calculated the UnCox to be near 1500 uA/V^2. I am designing a two stage amplifier using this model CMOS, and this variation is affecting adversely on the dimensions of the MOSFETS.